# Why both display: none; and visibility: hidden; in Bootstrap .hidden class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why does the bootstrap class `.hidden` look like this:

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Actually also why is the `visibility: hidden;`  used here when `display: none` removes the element? Any help would be appreciated thanks.
[Code of my bootstrap version.](http://pastebin.com/JSL8nt4q) (line 5673)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide), there are 2 classes used for `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`

From the documentation,

```
// Classes
.hidden {
   display: none !important;
}
.invisible {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Not sure where you got the information that said the `.hidden` class uses both `visibility` and `display`.

Comment: This is my bootstrap file: http://pastebin.com/JSL8nt4q. Looking at the code it looks like I wrote.

Comment: Not in BS 3.3.7 which is the lastest version it ain't. Perhaps you have an old or edited version.